# Odbc_fdw.control is missing

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, cartodb

I am using cartoDB and Postgres 9.3 including PostGIS. When I try to create development user in cartoDB I get this error:

```
'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS odbc_fdw SCHEMA public;'
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/odbc_fdw.control": No such file or directory
```

Also, when I try to run odbc_fdw extension inside Postgres I get the same error.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the files `odbc_fdw--0.0.1.sql` and `odbc_fdw.control` in the `extension` subdirectory of the PostgreSQL share directory.
You can find the PostgreSQL share directory with `pg_config --sharedir`.

In your case the files have to be installed in `/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension`.

Comment: Thanks!

So should it be:
 pg_config --sharedir /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension

If so, I get next error:
pg_config: invalid argument: /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension

Sorry I am newbie.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I have improved the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this files can be found on the internet?

Comment: Thanks it works!

Now I am getting a new but seems related error:

 could not access file "$libdir/odbc_fdw": No such file or directory

Comment: Well, you have to put the file `odbc_fdw.so` into the directory you get from `pg_config --libdir`. Usually `make install` installs all required files, what did you do?

Comment: I just found the files on the internet and saved it into the extension subdirectory.