# $libdir/odbc_fdw is missilng

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, cartodb

I am using cartoDB and Postgres 9.3 including PostGIS. When I try to create development user in cartoDB I get this error:

`PG::Error: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/odbc_fdw": No such file or directory: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS odbc_fdw SCHEMA publi`c

Also, when I try to run odbc_fdw extension inside Postgres I get the same error.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Isn't that the same as your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584347/odbc-fdw-control-is-missing

Comment: That is solved, this is new but similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you did not install odbc_fdw properly.

For the following I assume that you are using UNIX.

- Check out or download and unpack the source code.
- See that PostgreSQL is installed, including header files (if you use installation packages, this is often a "devel" Package).
- See that [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) and its header files are installed.
- Make sure that `pg_config` is in your `PATH`.

Then change into the odbc_fdw directory and type

```
make          # compile odbc_fdw
make install  # install it in the correct place
```

You might have to be `root` for the second step.

PostgreSQL searches extension libraries like `odbc_fdw.so` in the directory you can display with `pg_config --libdir`.

Comment: At least on windows, and in our experience (see my answer) the real folder where extension libraries are search for is not exactly the one reported by "pg_config --libdir", but it is a "postgresql" folder inside it. Instead, the command "pg_config --sharedir" gave the exact folder (ie: \share\postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will help:

```
~/dev/pg $ git clone https://github.com/CartoDB/odbc_fdw.git
... Some output ...
~/dev/pg $ sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev postgresql-server-dev-9.5
... Some output ...
~/dev/pg $ cd odbc_fdw
~/dev/pg/odbc_fdw $ make
... Some output ...
~/dev/pg/odbc_fdw $ sudo make install
... Some output ...
~/dev/pg/odbc_fdw $ psql
psql (9.5.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create extension odbc_fdw;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# CREATE SERVER odbc_server
postgres-#   FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER odbc_fdw
postgres-#   OPTIONS (dsn 'test');
CREATE SERVER
postgres=# CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
postgres-#   SERVER odbc_server
postgres-#   OPTIONS (username 'root', password '');
CREATE USER MAPPING
postgres=# CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
postgres-#   odbc_table (
... Table details ...
postgres(#   );
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
postgres=# select * from odbc_table;
ERROR:  Connecting to driver
postgres=# \q
~/dev/pg/odbc_fdw $
```

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue on a Windows 7 machine, and solved it. The odbc_fdw was this (for pg 9.6 and 64bit platform): http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/372-ODBC-FDW-now-supports-9.5-and-9.6.html

The issue was: the above compiled library .zip had two folders:

- **\lib**, which contained only "odbc_fdw.dll"
- **\share**, which contained an "extension" subfolder (containing a .control file and several .sql files)
- two instruction .txt files

Since the above .zip had no install info in the .txt files or elsewhere, as inexperienced postgres users, we thought to copy

- "odbc_fdw.dll" under [postgres_install]\pg96\lib (directly)
- the "extension" subfolder under [postgres_install]\pg96\share (directly)

And, trying to install the extension, got the above error... "could not access file "$libdir/odbc_fdw": No such file or directory: ". Also issuing the CLI command

[postgres_install]\pg_config --libdir

the answer was "correct": "C:/POSTGR~1/pg96/lib"

Only later we realized that both \lib and \share had a **"postgresql" subfolder**, and we tried to move

- "odbc_fdw.dll" under [postgres_install]\pg96\lib\postgresql
- the "extension" subfolder under [postgres_install]\pg96\share\postgresql

and, after restarting the service it worked, no errors. And we could create the extension, connect the foreign server through odbc and be able to query a foreing mysql test table, joining it with a local postgreql table... all ok.

So, the error message was a bit misleading, because you can't understand if somehow "$libdir" was not resolved correctly (after all the error message shows it unresolved) or, if it was, why the "file" was not found "there" where it is. ANd, also the .zip file instruction didn't mantion *where* to install those files.

Of course you have to guess that there is an implied **"postgresql" subfolder**, to take into account in both cases. That was sufficient, in our case...